# How to include manufacturer description without using a product attribute in Magento Community Edition? PHP / XML / MySQL

Tags: php, magento

In a normalized database schema, the manufacturers would have their own attributes like, for example, name, description, address, phone number.

The manufacturer description is something that is useful for the product pages. Many ecommerce sites show a manufacturer description on every product page.

As far as I know, in Magento you would have to create a product attribute, "Manufacturer description" or something like that. If, for example, ABC Corporation has 1,000 products, you would have to update all 1,000 every time you changed your description for ABC Corporation.

Is that the only reasonably easy way to do it?

Or is there a more database normal way of doing it, where a single, atomic update would result in all the manufacturer's items showing an updated value on the front end?

Comment: you can create another module one table that hold the manufacture_id and information like name/description/etc... then you load this model in each product based on the attribute value from the product !

Answer (score 0):

Create a module with the following contents:

- **setup script** that creates a manufacturer table like desired
- **model** and **resource model** classes for manufacturer
- **grid** to manage the manufacturers (this is quite complicated, you should follow a tutorial [like this](http://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified) or copy the basics from another module)
- manufacturer **block** and **template** to render HTML for manufacturer info. You will use it as frontend model for the manufacturer_id attribute (see below)
- **setup script** that adds a product attribute `manufacturer_id`
- **source model** for the manufacturer id, so you can select the manufacturer from a dropdown instead of typing in the id

Answer (score 0):

To display manufacturer description on product page without using product attribute you need to create new table **"manufacturer_info"** and this table contains information of manufacturer id as well as description.

Table is something like this

manufacturer_id  |  description

To add description, you need to create new module which will display all the shop brand s and description in grid. When you edit manufacture one form will appear and in that form add description and save it to database.

After saving description, You can display it on product page based on manufacture_id.

To get current manufacture use following code

$_product = $this->getProduct();

$manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');

$manufacturerId = $_product->getManufacturer();

**Use manufacturer_id for getting description from newly created table**

I hope this helps.